# Multiprocessing a for loop - got errors

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have some code in Python and I wanna do it with multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import Value
import time
import math

resault_a = []
resault_b = []
resault_c = []


def make_calculation_one(numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        resault_a.append(math.sqrt(number**3))


def make_calculation_two(numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        resault_a.append(math.sqrt(number**4))


def make_calculation_three(numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        resault_c.append(math.sqrt(number**5))


number_list = list(range(1000000))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mp.set_start_method("fork")
    p1 = mp.Process(target=make_calculation_one, args=(number_list))
    p2 = mp.Process(target=make_calculation_two, args=(number_list))
    p3 = mp.Process(target=make_calculation_three, args=(number_list))

    start = time.time()
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)
```

1. I got an empty array, where is the problem?
2. I got some errors:
   "Process Process-1:
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
   self.run()"

How can I fix it?

TNX

Comment: I get the same errors that A. Herlas reported: you're not calling your `make_calculation_*` functions properly so everything fails with `TypeError` exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

1. The major problem is that the *args* argument to the `Process` initializer requires a tuple or list. You are specifying `args=(number_list)`. The parentheses around `number_list` does *not* make this a tuple. Without the comma you just have a parenthesized expression, i.e. a list. So instead of passing a single argument that is a list, you are passing 10,000 arguments, while your "worker" functions only take 1 argument. You need: `args=(number_list,)`.
2. Your worker functions are doing calculations but neither printing nor returning the results of these calculations. Assuming you want to return the results, you need a mechanism for doing so. If you are using `multiprocessing.Process` then the usual solution is to pass to the worker function a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance to which the worker function can `put` the results (see below). You can also use a multiprocessing pool (also see below).
3. Your timing is not quite right. You have started the child processes and immediately set `end` without waiting for the tasks to complete. To get the actual time, `end` should only be set when the child processes have finished creating their results.

**Using `Process` with queues**

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import math

def make_calculation_one(numbers, out_q):
    out_q.put([math.sqrt(number**3) for number in numbers])

def make_calculation_two(numbers, out_q):
    out_q.put([math.sqrt(number**4) for number in numbers])

def make_calculation_three(numbers, out_q):
    out_q.put([math.sqrt(number**5) for number in numbers])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # We only want one copy of `number_list`, i.e. in our main process.
    # But there is actually no need to convert to a list:
    number_list = range(1000000)
    mp.set_start_method("fork")
    out_q_1 = mp.Queue()
    out_q_2 = mp.Queue()
    out_q_3 = mp.Queue()
    # Create pool of size 3:
    p1 = mp.Process(target=make_calculation_one, args=(number_list, out_q_1))
    p2 = mp.Process(target=make_calculation_two, args=(number_list, out_q_2))
    p3 = mp.Process(target=make_calculation_three, args=(number_list, out_q_3))
    start = time.time()
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()

    results = []
    # Get return values:
    results.append(out_q_1.get())
    results.append(out_q_2.get())
    results.append(out_q_3.get())
    end = time.time()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()

    print(end - start)
```

**Using a shared memory array to pass the number list and to return the results**

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import math

def make_calculation_one(numbers, results):
    for idx, number in enumerate(numbers):
        results[idx] = math.sqrt(number**3)

def make_calculation_two(numbers, results):
    for idx, number in enumerate(numbers):
        results[idx] = math.sqrt(number**4)

def make_calculation_three(numbers, results):
    for idx, number in enumerate(numbers):
        results[idx] = math.sqrt(number**5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # We only want one copy of `number_list`, i.e. in our main process
    number_list = mp.RawArray('d', range(1000000))
    mp.set_start_method("fork")
    results_1 = mp.RawArray('d', len(number_list))
    results_2 = mp.RawArray('d', len(number_list))
    results_3 = mp.RawArray('d', len(number_list))
    # Create pool of size 3:
    p1 = mp.Process(target=make_calculation_one, args=(number_list, results_1))
    p2 = mp.Process(target=make_calculation_two, args=(number_list, results_2))
    p3 = mp.Process(target=make_calculation_three, args=(number_list, results_3))
    start = time.time()
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    end = time.time()

    print(end - start)
```

**Using a multiprocessing pool**

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import math

def make_calculation_one(numbers):
    return [math.sqrt(number**3) for number in numbers]

def make_calculation_two(numbers):
    return [math.sqrt(number**4) for number in numbers]

def make_calculation_three(numbers):
    return [math.sqrt(number**5) for number in numbers]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # We only want one copy of `number_list`, i.e. in our main process
    number_list = range(1000000)
    mp.set_start_method("fork")
    # Create pool of size 3:
    pool = mp.Pool(3)
    start = time.time()
    async_results = []
    async_results.append(pool.apply_async(make_calculation_one, args=(number_list,)))
    async_results.append(pool.apply_async(make_calculation_two, args=(number_list,)))
    async_results.append(pool.apply_async(make_calculation_three, args=(number_list,)))

    # Now wait for results:
    results = [async_result.get() for async_result in async_results]
    end = time.time()
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(end - start)
```

**Conclusion**

Since your calculations yield a type readily supported by shared memory, the second code example above should result in the best performance. You could also adapt the multiprocessing pool example to use shared memory.

Comment: wow TNX it works great!
Using a multiprocessing pool: it's the fastest way as I saw.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting some other error:

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: make_calculation_one() takes 1 positional argument but 1000000 were given
```

but if I change these line accordingly then it works:

```
     p1 = mp.Process(target=make_calculation_one, args=([number_list]))
     p2 = mp.Process(target=make_calculation_two, args=([number_list]))
     p3 = mp.Process(target=make_calculation_three, args=([number_list]))
```

Comment: Hi TNX for your comment. I edited my code, PLS check it again I forgot to remove some rows.
I tried what you said but I got empties verbs resault_a, resault_b and resault_c

Comment: you have some other problems now, variable handle in a multiprocessing environment...

Answer (score 0):

The function that is run in a worker `Process` cannot access data in the parent process.

If the "fork" start method is used, it would have access to the *copy* of that data in the forked process.
But modifying that would not alter the value in the parent process.

In this case, the easiest thing to do it to create a `multiprocessing.Array`, and pass that to the process to use.

```
import math
import multiprocessing as mp


def make_calculation_one(numbers, res):
    for idx, number in enumerate(numbers):
        res[idx] = math.sqrt(number**3)


number_list = list(range(10000))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    result_a = mp.Array("d", len(number_list))
    p1 = mp.Process(target=make_calculation_one, args=(number_list, result_a))
    p1.start()
    p1.join()

print(sum(result_a))
```

This code prints the value 3999500012.4745193.